# JavaScript: how to control progress speed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any option to increase and decrease the speed of the progress?
Sometimes progress takes time and sometime very slow to finish:

```
var value = 0,
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      value = ((+value) + .1).toFixed(1);
      if(value == 80.5) clearInterval(interval);   
      $('p').html(value+'%');
    },2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/zjdBh/13/

Comment: just increase the last number, the `2` at the end of the interval ?

Comment: @adeneo counting not ending and also resulr showing more than one digit like this 99.561321654651615% :(

Answer (score 2):

You'll note that your code is using [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval). This global JavaScript function is used for periodically executing code at a given time interval. It takes two arguments for its typical usage (which is the way you are using it here). It returns a unique ID that can be used to identify your particular interval function (since multiple ones can be set up simultaneously).

The first argument is a function to be executed on the interval. Your function is the anonymous function:

```
function() {
    value = ((+value) + .1).toFixed(1);
    if (value == 80.5) clearInterval(interval);   
    $('p').html(value + '%');
}
```

This function will increase the percentage progress on each execution.

The second argument is an integer number for the number of milliseconds (thousandths of a second) to let elapse before the function from the first argument is executed. This is the key part for your question, I believe. Your code has `2` (on the last line of your posted code), so it will wait 2 milliseconds before executing your function (which increments the percentage progress), and then it will wait 2 more milliseconds, then execute the same function again, etc.

By simply changing the value of the second argument, you can change how fast or slow your function executes each time, which changes how fast or slow your percentage increases. So if you set it to `500`, then `setInterval` will wait for a half a second before each execution of the function.

You can read about the other JavaScript timer functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Timers), in particular about [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval), which your code uses in the anonymous function to end the interval when you reach `80.5%`.

Comment: @ajp14243 the best way is use `jQuery` or any other `JavaScript` isn't ?

Comment: If you want to increase or decrease the percentage progression, just change the `2` that's on your last line of posted code to match the number of milliseconds you want between each update to the percentage value. You shouldn't need to make any other changes if your goal is to increment a percentage count up to `80.5%` and then stop.

Comment: thanks for your help Unfortunately `2` speed not enough sometimes :(, do you have any other function for me

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Not enough in that you want it to go faster or slower than 2 ms?

Comment: not really, the use of progress is for `RAPHEAL BAR CHART`. As beginner I didn't find solution in that plug in. Sometimes graph is very small. counting not finishing when bar chart reach full height

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil So you want the progress indicator to match the growth of the bar chart? Or does it already match the growth of the bar chart and just stops too early?

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil It sounds like you want to register a callback function with each animation step in Raphael. That's a rather different question from this one, so you should open a new question, and explain in great detail what you need to do and what you've attempted. Include that jsfiddle link.

Comment: unfortunately there is no enough people to answer for such questions, there are three questions already pending on the basis of raphael

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$(function(){
    var value1 = 0;
    var value2 = 0;
    var span1 = $('#val1');
    var span2 = $('#val2');
    var interval1 = setInterval(function(){
        span1.text(++value1);
        if (value1 === 80) {
            clearInterval(interval1);   
            clearInterval(interval2);
            interval1 = null;
            interval2 = null;
            span2.text(5);
        }
    }, 100); // you can change speed here
    var interval2 = setInterval(function() {
        span2.text(value2++ % 10);
    }, 70);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
<hr>
<p><span id="val1">0</span>.<span id="val2">1</span>%</p>
</body>
```

Comment: nice work :) I was looking for this kind of solution. I'm facing an issue on this when `value1 === 95.5` :(

Comment: @MuhammedAthimannil Just use `value1 === 95`, because `.5`is separately put by another `interval2` as `span2.text(5)`